# H2 maintain use-count column of a row automatically with computed column expression

Tags: sql, h2

How would I define a computedColumnExpression in H2 that increments a field of the row with each update of the row and starts at zero.

Well, by definition the computedColumnExpression is run every time an update occurs. But

- how can the previous value of the usecount field of the updated row be referenced and
- how is the initial insert handled?

I would start with a column definition like

```
"usecount" INT4 (1+(SELECT IFNULL("usecount",0) from "data" WHERE ID=XXXX))
```

but what should I use for the XXXX ?

I looked at triggers and thought to just update `newRow` in the `fire` method, but this does not seem to have any effect.

Given the first answer and my unsuccessful attempt I need to mention that the table already exist and I need the table definition to be an `ALTER TABLE "data" ADD COLUMN`. I would not have thought that it makes a difference.-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a declaration like this:

```
create table foo (pk int primary key, 
                  usecount int as usecount + 1);
```

... where the rightmost `usecount` references the previous value. When you insert the row just insert a `0` value:

```
insert into foo values (42, 0);
```

... which will automatically increment the value to `1`.

If you already have the table, you can add the column in two steps:

```
alter table foo add column usecount int default 0;
alter table foo alter column usecount int as usecount + 1;
```

Comment: Yes, this works. Except it does not seem to work with `ALTER TABLE "data" ADD COLUMN`. Sorry, I would not have thought that this makes a difference. See edit :-(

Comment: Updated answer with how to solve the `ALTER TABLE` case with a workaround!

Comment: Cool, this finally works. I thought I had tried this, but I must have made another mistake then and was unsure whether it could work at all because the 'as' syntax is not officially listed here: http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#alter_table_alter_column, or am I missing something?

Comment: No, I think you are right. I'm adding a [pull request](https://github.com/h2database/h2database/pull/729) for the grammar documentation...